# Update Accumulated Value with CTE error because of decimal datatype (SQL)

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am trying to get the accumulated value of the column `MontanteRecuperacao` into `montanterecuperacao_acumulada`, by date and contract.

But the decimal datatype is becoming a problem and I don't know why, this works when the variables are of INT type.

This is the error message

> Msg 4187, Level 16, State 1, Procedure spCalculaRecuperacao, Line 123
> Data type decimal of receiving variable cannot store all values of the data type decimal of column 'montanterecuperacao_acumulada' without data loss.

Code:

```
DECLARE @MontanteRecuperacao_running DECIMAL,     
        @montanterecuperacao_acumulada_running DECIMAL, 
        @Contrato VARCHAR(10) = '' ;

WITH CTE AS
(
    SELECT TOP 100 PERCENT
        MontanteRecuperacao, montanterecuperacao_acumulada, ContratoId  
    FROM
        MovimentoRecuperacao 
    ORDER BY 
        [ContratoId], [DtReferencia] DESC
)
UPDATE CTE 
SET @montanterecuperacao_acumulada_running = montanterecuperacao_acumulada = 
       CASE 
          WHEN @Contrato <> ContratoId 
             THEN montanterecuperacao_acumulada 
             ELSE @montanterecuperacao_acumulada_running - @MontanteRecuperacao_running 
       END,
    @MontanteRecuperacao_running = MontanteRecuperacao,
    @Contrato = ContratoId
```

Answer (score 1):

You've declared your `DECIMAL` parameters without specifying precision or scale:

```
@MontanteRecuperacao_running DECIMAL , @montanterecuperacao_acumulada_running DECIMAL
```

The default values are `DECIMAL(18,0)`, which is essentially an integer. In order to get the behavior you desire, you'll need to assess your data for proper values to assign.